# Good alternative for Adobe AIR and Zinc in Flash 10 + AS 2.0

Tags: flash, air, mdm-zinc

I'm making a Flash app in Flash 10 and ActionScript 2.0 and need support for calling an EXE with some params and minimizing/close the application.

Neither Adobe AIR nor Zinc don't seem to support some code I made and I'm looking for a very simple alternative? Does anyone know about any?

Answer (score 2):

I'm the project owner of [HIppoHX](http://hippohx.com/), an Open Source alternative to AIR based on Haxe and SWHX that does what you need (plus it's fully extensible). The project is a little bit on hold, to be honest, but maybe the biggest hurdle is redistributing the flash player. Be sure to read [Flash player redistribution](http://wiki.hippohx.com/Flash_player_redistribution) on the Wiki.

Answer (score 1):

We've been toying with mProjector.  While it feels like a work in progress, it seems pretty lightweight, very straight-forward from an actionscript perspective, and if you use multiple windows a new stage is used for each window/swf -- a few singletons or poorly written event listeners won't matter as much as they would for a similar app built in air...  my 2p.

Answer (score 0):

Does AIR 2.0 help

http://labs.adobe.com/wiki/index.php/AIR_2:Release_Notes

> You can open document files in the
>   application the user has set up as the
>   default opening application. Launching
>   executables or script files is not
>   permitted unless the application is
>   packaged in a native installer.

Comment: It seems it doesn't have support for AS2.0 neither.